# image classification using SVM technique in opencv

Tags: opencv, svm

I need to train the sample image set to classification of them. But i have bit knowledge about the SVM technique to do the coding stuff. please help me to do the programming part of that.

Comment: I used [this](https://github.com/royshil/FoodcamClassifier) to get me started. its an excellent example. it uses SURF features, SVM and KMeans clustering. more details about it can be found [here](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2011/08/25/a-simple-object-classifier-with-bag-of-words-using-opencv-2-3-w-code/).

Answer (score 2):

The OpenCV documentation of the SVM provides a small example on how to use it: [link](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/ml/introduction_to_svm/introduction_to_svm.html)